# modifying imported functions in go

Tags: go

I could override the builtin `print()` function's behavior by defining another `print()`  in scope, as in https://play.golang.org/p/Y2ly31oXU67

Is it possible in go to alter the behavior on-the-fly of an imported function, say `fmt.Println()`?

Comment: The playground example declares a function named `print` at package scope.  The example does not alter the builtin `print` function declared in the universe scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "on-the-fly"?   The playground example declares a function at package scope.  If a compile time declaration works for you, then import some different package with name "fmt" and implement whatever functions you need in that package.  Something like https://play.golang.org/p/AryQ8cykFrG

Comment: @CeriseLimón, yes - your 2nd comment would work for me. thanks! I'd gladly mark that as the accepted answer if you can reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import a different package with name "fmt" and implement whatever functions you need in that package. Here's an example:

File go.mod:

```
module test
```

File main.go

```
package main

import (
    "test/fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

File fmt/fmt.go:

```
package fmt

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func Println(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
    log.Printf(msg)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AryQ8cykFrG).

The code in this answer does not modify the imported function as asked in the question.

Comment: also, TIL: Go playground has support for multiple files!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to 'alter' a builtin function, look at the very fine monkey patch utility https://github.com/bouk/monkey (And pay attention to the warnings, it's only really useful in test functions, and I for one reject any prod code that imports that package)